# How to detect if user auto logged-in with Google One Tap

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

I'm trying to tag my user by theirs login method. I want to detect if user clicked Google One-Tap and logged-in or he/she is logged-in automatically.

I'm calling one-tap by `retrieve(request);`. Below code runs succesfully to log my users in but I cannot detect if they came by in automatic way or they clicked.

```
g.retrieve(request).then(success, error);
```

Comment: Wonder what you would do with this info? Would the UX be different in these cases, or is it just for analytics purposes?

Comment: It is for analyrics purposes @StevenSoneff.

Comment: We're working on a new version of the library, so there isn't any plan to add more functionality to the existing one, but will keep this in mind for v2. Feel free to reach out sso@google.com